# Does Quantlib FloatingRateBond support SOFR index?

Tags: quantlib, sofr, floating-rate

I am trying to use Quantlib to price FloatingRateBond, Thanks to some other posts on the stack I managed to do it for Ibor indexes. I tried to use the SOFR, but I didn't succeed, I couldn't get around the SOFR being fixed at the end of the period as opposed to Ibor, as well as the compounding of the fixing. Is there a way to build a FloatingRateBond based on SOFR in QuantLib?

Comment: Resetting in arrears may not be the only new feature of your SOFR instruments. Some have lockout periods, lookback periods, etc.

Comment: Indeed, I have been looking to ISDA doc and it seems that there are few conventions to determine the reference period used for the compounding. If someone is interested:
https://www.isda.org/a/alEgE/A40393158-v18.0-ISDA_Memorandum_Compounding-RFRs-under-2006-Definitions.pdf .
Based on my research I don't think QuantLib support them

Comment: In addition to the new overnight RFRs, there are conventions for floaters reset from a daily index in Brazil (CDI), Chile (Camara), and many others. I suggest you document exactly what you need, maybe make reference implementations in Python or Excel (explicit calculations, not library calls) and make a suggestion in https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/issues . See, for example, https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/issues/1089